Centroids result in NONE while trying to re-implement the kmeans algorithm
I have defined specific function in my project of re-implementing the kmeans algorithm but at the point where the centroids are ment to be re-assigned and obtain newer values, they come out as NONE.
def plot_clusters(data, labels, centroids, iteration):
    pca = PCA(n_components=2)
    data_2d = pca.fit_transform(data)
    centroids_2d = pca.transform(centroids)
    clear_output(wait=True)
    plt.title(f'Iteration{iteration}')
    plt.scatter(x=data_2d[:,0], y=data_2d[:,1], c=labels)
    plt.scatter(x=centroids_2d[:,0], y=centroids_2d[:,1])
    plt.show()

max_iteration = 100
k = 7

centroids = random_centroids(data, k)
#print(f'Centroids formed {centroids}')
old_centroids = pd.DataFrame()
iteration = 1

while iteration < max_iteration and not centroids.equals(old_centroids):
    old_centroids = centroids
    labels = get_labels(data, centroids)
    centroids = new_centroids(data, labels, k)
    print(f'Iteration {iteration}: Centroids {centroids}')
    if centroids is not None:
        plot_clusters(data, labels, centroids, iteration)
    else:
        print("Centroids is None")
    iteration +=1

some previously defined functions that i had tested and they worked include:
def random_centroids(data, k):
    centroids = []
    for i in range(k):
        centroid = data.apply(lambda x: float(x.sample())) #sample func picks a random number from each feature
        centroids.append(centroid)
    return pd.concat(centroids, axis=1)

def get_labels(data, centroids):
    distances = centroids.apply(lambda x: np.sqrt(((data-x)**2).sum(axis=1)))
                                #Geometric distances formulae
    return distances.idxmin(axis=1)

#Obtain Geometric mean of each features(cluster centroids) 
def new_centroids(data, labels,k):     
    data.groupby(labels).apply(lambda x: np.exp(np.log(x).mean())).T

I have tried to put checks at every step of the code by using if then code but the results are the same. I do not understand why the random_centroids that work independently can't work in a defined function..
this line of code defines my intention while iteration < max_iteration and not centroids.equals(old_centroids): implying that so far the iteration are less than 100 (as defined) and new_centroids not equal to the old_centroids( the centroids continuies to change) the iteration will run.
But I am getting error warning
Iteration 1: Centroids None
Centroids is None
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[24], line 9
      6 old_centroids = pd.DataFrame()
      7 iteration = 1
----> 9 while iteration < max_iteration and not centroids.equals(old_centroids):
     10     old_centroids = centroids
     11     labels = get_labels(data, centroids)

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'equals'


new_centroids does not return anything (so, None), and you are using it as if it returned the new centroids.

okay. I just saw the omission. Thanks
